# Firebase authentication: signInWithEmailAndPassword method dont respond at all

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

I am getting problem in authentication in firebase through android app. everything is fine with code and connections. But I still don't get authenticated. I have done all the requisites like

- Have enabled email/password sign in methods in firebase
- Added all the required dependencies in build.gradle
- checked with changing the rules (user) to null and ! null.
- connections is done successfully

the problem is inside the `signInWithEmialAndPassword` method, neither the if nor else statement gets executed. Why is this so? I have searched a lot but all in vain. I am using emulator NEXUS 5X API 26 not actual device.
Here is the code..

```
package com.example.abid.fireauthapp;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    // ..
    private EditText mEmailField;
    private EditText mPasswordField;
    private Button mLoginButton;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
   // private DatabaseReference rootRef;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mEmailField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailField);
        mPasswordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordField);
        mLoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();



        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());

                    //show a welcome messgage and start a new activity
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class));

                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                }
                // ...
            }
        };
        mLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                StartSignIn();

            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (mAuthListener == null) {
            mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
    }


    private void StartSignIn() {
        String email = mEmailField.getText().toString();
        String pass = mPasswordField.getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email) || TextUtils.isEmpty(pass)){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fields are empty...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this,new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You are sign in..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class));

                            //These Both if and else statement dont get executed... Why ??

                            if (user == null) {
                                Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failed", task.getException());
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error Occured",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Signed In successfully..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }

                            // ...
                        }
                    });
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Show code to help understand..

Comment: I have showed the code please

Comment: @amuyu kindly guide me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code like this.

```
...
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You are sign in..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class));
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


                }
```

What happens?

Comment: Thank you now its working :) there were also some hidden problems. thank you for the response..